# Configure symbol quote expansion in clojure zprint

Tags: clojure, pretty-print

Is there a way to avoid having `zprint` write `'my-symbol` as `(quote my-symbol)`?  I am aware it is the reader that converts it to that form. 
 However I would expect zprint to be configurable to produce the more idiomatic format which is the default for clojure.pprint.

```clj
(require '[zprint.core :as zp])
(zp/zprint '(def foo 'my-symbol))
;; (def foo (quote my-symbol))


(require '[clojure.pprint :as pp])
(pp/pprint '(def foo 'my-symbol))
;; (def foo 'my-symbol)
```

Comment: Hmm. Ideally it seems like zprint would use clojure.pprint as its base level form printer, but I guess it doesn't. Here's the line in pprint that takes care of this https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/pprint/dispatch.clj#L49

Answer (score 1):

See related issue: 
https://github.com/kkinnear/zprint/issues/121

Following bfabry's comment, as a workaround, we can use pprint to create the nicely quoted string, and then pass it through zprint for formatting:

```clj
(require '[zprint.core :as zp])
(require '[clojure.pprint :as pp])

(-> '(def foo 'my-symbol)
    pp/pprint
    with-out-str 
    (zp/zprint 40 {:parse-string? true}))
(def foo 'my-symbol)
nil
```